# Mokutil does'nt work in Google Cloud Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, debian, google-compute-engine

I have installed Debian 12 on Google Cloud Compute Engine, and I used Mokutil to install a certificate, but I couldn't.

```
mokutil --import certification.cer
```

After rebooting, the Mokutil key management screen appears, but I cannot enter the key.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Neither `google-compute-engine` nor `uefi` are related to your problem. Remove those tags and replace them with ones appropriate for Debian,  Mokutil, and Crowdstrike.